# Are nuclei just as efficient as individual protons at generating magnetic fields? Or are they less efficient, if less efficient then how much so?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, charge, ferromagnetism

How efficient are moving nuclei at generating magnetic fields,
also how does the efficiency of atoms compare compare to charged particles and nuclei? Assuming the nuclei have the same number of protons as the number of protons being compared, and that they are moving at the same speed.

Comment: How do you define "efficiency" in this context?

Comment: @Nick I think the most realistic interpretation of the question is if we compare the magnetic moment of the nuclei to the sum of their protons.

Comment: how strong of a magnetic field it creates if it moves in the same velocity as individual protons also being used to create a magnetic field

Comment: does the properties(such as spin) or the arrangement of the particles in nuclei make them less efficient at generating magnetic  fields than individual protons in the same velocity?

Comment: what perterh said sounds like what I'm asking, but I must know what exactly is a magnetic moment, you see i'm trying to see what the maximum magnetic field I can generate with something ferromagnetic is, an I thought I might be able to use it's atomic number to see the total number of protons in the material to see the maximum electromagnetic force it can create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nuclei will have more protons within it hence making it a higher charge. A changed particle will only have a small change From its original balance. I believe a nuclei will be more efficient however it will be only a positive charge. So it wouldn't be a dipole it would only be singular

Comment: But since it is more massive, you need a higher energy per nucleon to have the same current...